# How to use functions in Value.Eval_expr, Value.Eval_op etc modules of Frama-c Value plugin

Tags: ocaml, frama-c

I am trying to create a frama-c plugin. This plugin depends upon Frama-c Value plugin. I want to obtain and print value set of all the lvalue(s) in a C source code. In order to do that I want to use functions available in Value.Eval_exprs, Value.Eval_op etc. like `Eval_exprs.lval_to_precise_loc`.

Unfortunately I am unable to figure out a way to use these function in my plugin. I tried to follow steps mentioned in section 4.10.1 (Registration through a .mli file) of Frama-c Plugin Development Guide and added `PLUGIN_DEPENDENCIES:=Value` in my Makefile but I noticed that `Value.mli` file is empty and no function is exposed through this file. After that I looked at `db.ml` file in `kernel` directory and couldn't find any module that can be used to access all the functions available in Eval_exprs, Eval_op etc.

Is there any way to access these functions of Value plugin from other plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple mechanisms are available to use the results of a Frama-C plugin programatically:

1. through the `Db` module, that contains functions to access the results of many "core" plugins
2. through calls to the "dynamic" API (module `Dynamic`)
3. through the interface of the plugin (e.g. `Value.mli` in your case)

The first two approaches are deprecated, and will eventually disappear. Furthermore, approach 1. is not available for user-written plugins. This is why the developer manual emphasizes approach 3.

That being said, currently, the results of Value are available using approach 1 (only). Inside your plugin, you can simply write `!Db.Value.eval_expr` or `!Db.Value.eval_lval` to evalate an expression and a left-value respectively. This will work automatically. You should still declare Value as a dependency of your plugin (`PLUGIN_DEPENDENCIES:=Value` as you found out), as this will be required in the next version of Frama-C. All the *internal* modules of Value, such as `Eval_exprs`, are **not** exported, intentionally. Most uses of Value's results can be written using the functions available in `Db.Value`.

Finally, `lval_to_precise_loc` is a pretty advanced function, as the returned locations have a type that is hard to use. `Db.Value.lval_to_loc` is nearly always a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I was able to obtain and print value set of lvalue(s) as following:                                                                      `let before = !Db.Value.access (Kstmt stmt)  lv   in 
    Format.fprintf out "value of lval : %a is: %a" Printer.pp_lval lv Db.Value.pretty before;`

Comment: I am finding it hard to obtain after state of the `stmt`  to obtain values set of lval after statement is executed. I think if I can get `after_state`, I can obtain after value set as:  `let _, after = !Db.Value.eval_lval ~with_alarms (Some Locations.Zone.bottom) after_state lv`. Can you please suggest a way to get after_state?

Comment: You can use `fold_stmt_state_callstack` to iterate over the results on a statement per analysis callstack. If you do not need the callstack, you can simply join all the possible states: `let state_after stmt =
  Db.Value.fold_stmt_state_callstack Cvalue.Model.join Cvalue.Model.bottom ~after:true stmt`

Comment: @ byako, Thanks for the response, but I can't find function `fold_stmt_state_callstack` in `db.ml`. I am working with Sodium version. Am I  missing something here?

Comment: You're right, this function was added in Magnesium, and this version has not been released yet. You can get the information for all callstacks on statement `s` using `Db.Value.AfterTable_By_Callstack.find s`.