# Frama-C: Display callstacks in the command line output

Tags: frama-c

When using the value analysis plug-in, one can use the GUI to display the values of a variable at a given program location (using the 'Values' tab). The values shown in this tab include the call stack corresponding to a particular value. E.g.:

```
fn1 -> fn2 -> fn3 | {values}
fn4 -> fn5 -> fn3 | {values}
```

On the command line, one can display the values of a variable when analysis reaches a program location by using `Frama_C_show_each(var)`. However, the corresponding call stack is not displayed.

Is there a way to tell Frama-C to output the call stack at a given program location to obtain information of the form (callstack, values) as in the GUI?

Thanks a lot in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Eva (former *Value analysis*) plug-in has an option to print callstacks:

```
-val-print-callstacks  When printing a message, also show the current call
                       stack (opposite option is -no-val-print-callstacks)
```

This, as well as other Eva options, is accessible via `frama-c -value-help`, or `frama-c -value-h`.

Otherwise, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132777) contains an example script which, combined with `Db.Value.get_stmt_state_callstack`, should allow crafting a custom way to print the desired information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this indeed works! Note that the stacks will be printed every time `Frama_C_show_each` is reached, or an assertion value is reported.